# SocketIO: basic socket.broadcast.emit not excluding sender

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have made this very small basic socket-io app that moves an objects position for every user connected to my app. So if user A is moving the object, its moving for user B and
same for the other way.

My problem now is that the user that is moving the object also is receiving the event for a new position but that shouldnt be possible with `socket.broadcast.emit('newPos', movementData);` or am I missing something here?

Why is it not excluding the sender?

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
//on connect
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  //if we receive new movement send it to all clients expect sender
  socket.on('movement', function(movementData) {
    console.log('received');  
        socket.broadcast.emit('newPos', movementData);
  });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

app.js

```
  // client
  var socket = io();
  // get object which holds position data
  var obj = app.getObjectByName('Cube');


  // save position data of user
  var x = obj.position.x;
  var y = obj.position.y;
  var z = obj.position.z;
  var oldPos;

  setInterval(function(){
    if(typeof oldPos !== "undefined" && (x !== obj.position.x || y !== obj.position.y || z !== obj.position.z)){
      // send new position to the server
      socket.emit('movement', {
        x: obj.position.x, y: obj.position.y, z: obj.position.z
      });
    }
    // erstelle / erneuere alte Position
     oldPos = obj.position.x;
     x = obj.position.x;
     y = obj.position.y;
     z = obj.position.z;
  },10000);

  //if we receive new data from the server then use it
  socket.on('newPos', function (pos) {
    console.log('receive new pos');
  });
```

Comment: Maybe because as others move (because of you) they automatically broadcast themselves (including you)?

Comment: I also thought of this, but I have the error already when I have the application open alone so only with one user, then it shouldnt be happening right?